# get json that have integer with volley library

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

i have a problem with get json with volley library.
this is my json:

```
{"result":1}
```

the php code count rows in mysql database and show result in this json file.
the number of count is integer.

and this is my code for get this json:

```
  private void getData () {
    //url + id of row that want to count
        String url = Config.DATA_URL_COUNT +"1";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Toast.makeText(this,error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

private void showJSON(String response) {

    int name = 0;


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULT);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = jsonObject.getInt(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String count = String.valueOf(name);
    rowcount_kargozarybime.setText(count); //insert result in textview
}
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $categoryid  = $_GET['categoryid'];

  define('HOST','144.76.10.250');
  define('USER','cp21983_test');
  define('PASS','*******');

  define('DB','cp21983_marivanjobs');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results=utf8,character_set_client=utf8,character_set_connection=utf8, character_set_database=utf8,character_set_server=utf8");

$sql="SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE categoryid='".$categoryid."'";

 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$rowcount));
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);

}
```

i well be thankfull if anyone can help me.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @f1sh the result not show in text view

Comment: Can you please add the response result format?

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
JSONObject respObject = new JSONObject(response);
int result = respObject.getInt("result");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a json object,not a json array. therefore use this code to get result count

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
int count = jsonObject.getInt("result");
rowcount_kargozarybime.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Comment: Thank you so much;)